# How to add and remove picture marker in archgis map?

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis

I am using the geosearch when i clicked on the location after that i am calling the add marker function, First time its show the marker but when i search again the location then it doesn't show anything. Here is my js

```
function addmarker(latt, longtt) {

    var pt1 = new Point(Number(longtt), Number(latt));

    var markersymbol1 = new PictureMarkerSymbol('images/marker.png', 10, 15);

    polygraphlayer.add( Graphic(pt1, markersymbol1));

     //map.add(polygraphlayer);

    //map.graphics.add(polygraphlayer);


}
$("#linkid").on("click",    function() {
    var dataLatt = $('#linkid')=='undefined'||$('#linkid')==''?'0,0':$('#linkid').data('latt');
    var splitdata = dataLatt.split(",");
    var latt = splitdata[0];
    var longt = splitdata[1];
    addmarker(latt, longt);

    //addmarker('28.833333', '76.666667');

});
```

[image]

> First time its show the marker but when i try to search other location
>   and click then marker doesn't show on that position previous marker on
>   that place.

Comment: Debug your code to see what values you are getting in the click handler. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: I am not getting any error